# C# - Concurrent I/O operations exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, viewmodel, webclient

I have a refresh button to update news in my WP7 application. When I double or triple click on the refresh button I am getting an error

```
"WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations" .
```

I think thats because It is sending the request triple times and making it crash. Here is my Click code.

```
    private void NewsRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = this.DataContext as MainPageViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.UpdateNews();
        }
    }
```

How can I turn it as "if It is busy cancel the process".

Comment: introduce private bool isPendingRefresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'easy' way (though not bullet proof):

```
private void NewsRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        NewsRefresh.Enabled = false;
        var vm = this.DataContext as MainPageViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.UpdateNews();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        NewsRefresh.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The more difficult approach would require more details on what exactly a MainPageViewModel is, and what UpdateNews() does.  Basically you need to store a state value wherever you are storing the WebClient instance.  Before using the WebClient you need check to see if you are already using it.  The issue comes when multiple threads may operate on a single instance, or if you multiple operations (other than UpdateNews).  When multiple threads are involved the easiest thing is to surround the usage of the WebClient with a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

Of course the other option is to not reuse the WebClient instance, rather create a new one for each new request.

**UPDATE**

Well, well, using DownloadStringAsync is certainly going to make things fun.  The above code Disabling the UI will not work unless you move the re-enabling code.  It would be easiest to go with my last suggestion and just create a new instance of WebClient.  I'm not real fond of WebClient myself and prefer using [WebRequest.Create](http://WebRequest.Create).

Comment: I will check this out. Btw, UpdateNews() is downloading the feed newsWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml"));

Answer (score 2):

WebClient isn't very flexible but if you really want to use it you can make use of the IsBusy property and then cancel ongoing operation. Then, once it's cancelled you can restart it. There is important problem with synchronization. The operation which consists of checking IsBusy and invoking CancelAsync isn't atomic. Luckily DownloadStringCompleted is dispatched to the UI thread so you don't need to bother about synchronization. The snippet below shows how can you achieve it. For simplicity it's Windows Forms.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    WebClient _WebClient;
    bool _UpdateNews;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _WebClient = new WebClient();
        _WebClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(_WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        _UpdateNews = false;
    }

    void _WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_UpdateNews)
        {
            _UpdateNews = false;
            UpdateNews();
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // Report error 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_WebClient.IsBusy)
        {
            _WebClient.CancelAsync();
            _UpdateNews = true;
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateNews();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateNews()
    {
        _WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084948/c-concurrent-i-o-operations-exception"));
    }
}
```

Comment: If refreshing is the only reason to cancel current operation you may want to remove _UpdateNews field and use e.Cancelled instead. I haven't included it in my snipped to make it more general.